# Al presionar la primera vez un botón para guardar una imagen de perfil me lanza error y al segundo clic me guarda la imagen, ¿Cómo puedo solucionarlo?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, imagen, react-hooks, onclick

tengo un problema en mi código de JavaScript, que actualmente tengo implementado un código para guardar imagen, funciona bien, el único drama es que al momento de presionar la primera vez el botón guardar me lanza un error y a la segunda vez me guarda la imagen, he intentado cambiando el orden de algunas cosas o variables, pero sigue igual, por si alguien podría ayudarme con ello. Dejo el código a continuación;

```
const toast = useRef(null);
const { data } = UseGetUser();
const [src, setSrc] = useState(null)
const [preview, setPreview] = useState(null)
const [image, setImage] = useState([])

const onClose = () => {
    setPreview(null);
}
const onCrop = preview => {
    setPreview(preview);
}

//Validación imagen null
const VALIDAR_NULL_IMG = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (preview === null) {
        toast.current.show({ severity: 'warn', summary: 'Imagen no seleccionada', detail: 'Seleccione una imagen para continuar', sticky: true, closable: true });
    } else {
        e.preventDefault()
        fetch(preview)
        .then(res => res.blob())
        .then(blob => {setImage(new File([blob], "fileName", { type: "image/png" }))})

        VALIDAR_MAX_SIZE();
    }
}
//Validación tamaño máximo
const VALIDAR_MAX_SIZE = () => {

    if (image.size > 2000000) {
        let size = parseInt(image.size);
        let ImgSize = size / 1048576;
        toast.current.show({ severity: 'warn', summary: 'Tamaño máximo excedido', detail: `Tamaño máximo: 2MB, tu imagen pesa: ${ImgSize.toFixed(1)}MB`, sticky: true, closable: true });
    } else {
        insImagen()
        toast.current.clear();
    }
}

//Eliminar Toast si ya ha seleccionado una imagen
if (preview !== null) {
    toast.current.clear();
}

//Fetch upload Img
const insImagen = () => {

    const endpoint = "http://ip/user/img/save";
    const formDataImg = new FormData();
    const idUser = data.id;
    const emailUser = data.email;

    formDataImg.append('img', image);
    formDataImg.append('iduser', idUser);
    formDataImg.append('email', emailUser);

    fetch(endpoint, {
        method: 'POST',
        body: formDataImg,
    }).then(x => x.json())
        .then(x => { console.log(x.message); FETCH_RESPONSE(x); WaitToast() })
        .catch(error => console.log(error));
}

const WaitToast = () => {
    setTimeout(() => {
        return onHide('displayImg')
    }, 2000);
}

//Cambiar a helper
const FETCH_RESPONSE = (x) => {

    const response = x;

    if (response === 'Formato invalido de imagen') {
        return toast.current.show({ severity: 'warn', summary: `${response}`, sticky: true, closable: true });
    }
    else if (response === 'Ocurrio un error') {
        return toast.current.show({ severity: 'error', summary: `${response}`, sticky: true, closable: true });

    } else if (response === 'Imagen Guardada') {
        return toast.current.show({ severity: 'success', summary: 'imagen guardada exitosamente', sticky: true, closable: true });
    }
}

return (
    <>
        <form className='flex flex-col gap-6 items-center'>
            <Avatar
                accept="image/jpeg, image/jpg, image/png"
                width={400}
                height={300}
                onCrop={onCrop}
                onClose={onClose}
                src={src}
            />

            {preview && <img src={preview} />}

            <label className='text-sm'>Solo se admiten jpg, jpeg y png. <br></br>Tamaño máximo: 2MB.</label>
            <button
                className={`${preview === null ? 'bg-blue-300 text-white p-3 w-40 rounded-lg flex items-center justify-center' : 'bg-blue-500 text-white p-3 w-40 rounded-lg hover:bg-blue-600 duration-200 flex items-center justify-center'}`}
                disabled={preview === null ? true : false}
                onClick={(e) => VALIDAR_NULL_IMG(e)}>
                Subir imagen
                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" className="h-5 w-5 ml-2" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor" strokeWidth={2}>
                    <path strokeLinecap="round" strokeLinejoin="round" d="M4 16v1a3 3 0 003 3h10a3 3 0 003-3v-1m-4-8l-4-4m0 0L8 8m4-4v12" />
                </svg>
            </button>
        </form>

        <Toast ref={toast} position="top-center" />
    </>
)
```

Yo creo que el error esta principalmente en el onClick o en la variable del onCrop, no lo tengo del todo claro a decir verdad, espero puedan ayudarme, gracias

Comment: cual es el error que recibis?

Comment: Es un error del Fetch Response, el que dice "Ocurrió un error", no un error de consola, así que mas allá de eso, no se donde esta fallando el tema de tener que presionar dos veces el botón guardar para que lo haga